# publish data from any local linux machine (no kafka) to remote machine where kafka is installed

Tags: apache-kafka

How to publish data from any local linux machine (where no kafka installed) to remote machine where kafka is installed?

Comment: Why are you under the impression that Kafka must be installed to send data to it?

Comment: Also, based on your previous questions, you've used Nifi. Have you never used the publish kafka processors?

Comment: Yeah I have used Publish Kafka, which is working fine.

Comment: Right, and Kafka does not need installed on the same machine as Nifi.

Comment: My question is, think that we have Kafka Installed on a remote machine(Y) and I have a another local Linux machine(X) where there is no Kafka and no Nifi, so is there any possibility that we do any configurations so that we can push the message on X machine and the Y machine can get those messages.

Comment: Yes. Kafka Clients are separate libraries than the broker runtime. Your question is similar to asking do you need to have Google installed locally to do a search

Answer (score 1):

You will either need to use Kafka's built-in command-line utilities or do it programmatically using one of the [supported clients](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients).

In order to produce messages from the command line, just [download Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads), un-tar it -

```
tar -xzf kafka_2.12-2.4.0.tgz
cd kafka_2.12-2.4.0
```

And then send some messages -

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list <KAFKA_HOST>:9092 --topic <TOPIC_NAME>
This is a message
This is another message
```

And if you want to do it programmatically - here's [an example](https://towardsdatascience.com/kafka-python-explained-in-10-lines-of-code-800e3e07dad1) how to do it with 10 lines of code using Python.